# Create directory and write files to a remote, password protected computer

Tags: python-2.7, remote-access

What I would like to do is be able to gain access to a computer over the network so I can create a new directory there that I will then save multiple files to throughout the rest of the script.

I have a script that creates a bunch of files that I need to save. The problem is that this script may be ran off any number of computers, but needs to save to the same computer. If I manually remote connect to the computer it prompts me for a username and password, but I am trying to just create a directory there. My code is below, along with the response I get.

```
if not os.path.exists(self.dirIn):
    tryPath = self.dirIn.split("/")[0:-1]
    tryPath = '/'.join(tryPath)
    if not os.path.exists(tryPath):
        os.mkdir(tryPath)
        os.mkdir(str(self.dirIn))
    else:
        os.mkdir(str(self.dirIn))
```

> WindowsError: [Error 1326] The user name or password is incorrect: '//computer/e$/directory/I/am/creating'

I am using Windows, Python27

Comment: Ia assume you __do__ have the correct _Admin usr/pwd_ to the remote computer (you're not some kind of a hacker :) ). Can you post the snippet where you connect to the computer? As a curiosity do you have the [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module installed?

Comment: Yes I do have the username and password! And I do have pywin32

Comment: Note that the whole logic in your code can be replaced by a simple `os.makedirs` call (it can create nested directories that don't exist like: _folder/that/does/not/exist_). Hmm, a simple `os.mkdir` call succeeds on a remote computer (using admin shares). 1st, do you want to provide the usr/pwd from your program or it's OK to use some previously saved credentials? 2nd: are workarounds accepted?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting makedirs, this was something I was unaware of! I am providing the user\pass in the program, but I found a fairly simple way to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to just map the drive to my computer using subprocess, do what I needed, and then unmap the drive (optional)

```
subprocess.Popen("net use E: \\\\computername\\E$ %s /USER:%s" % (password, username))
time.sleep(1)  # Short delay to allow E: drive to map before continuing

if not os.path.exists(self.dirIn):
        os.makedirs(self.dirIn)

subprocess.Popen("net use E: /delete")
```

I did run into problems without the sleep, my program wouldn't find the directory without it.

Comment: Yes, that's why I asked if workarounds are accepted, I was going to suggest _Map network drive_ which is what `net use` does.

Comment: Oops, I guess I got ahead myself. Thanks for the help!